# Sum of many keys (value) of many objects in an array with different data types

Tags: javascript

```
const products = [
{ product: 'banana', price: 3 },
{ product: 'mango', price: 6 },
{ product: 'potato', price: ' ' },
{ product: 'avocado', price: 8 },
{ product: 'coffee', price: 10 },
{ product: 'tea', price: '' },
]
```

Question: Find the sum of price of products using only reduce reduce(callback))?

This is my code:

```
const sumPrice = products.reduce(function(total, childObjectValue){
   if (childObjectValue.price != '' || childObjectValue.price != ' '){
    return total + childObjectValue.price
   } 
},0)
```

result ouput:  **9 810**

Help me resolve this problem, using only reduce() method !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```js
const products = [
{ product: 'banana', price: 3 },
{ product: 'mango', price: 6 },
{ product: 'potato', price: ' ' },
{ product: 'avocado', price: 8 },
{ product: 'coffee', price: 10 },
{ product: 'tea', price: '' },
]

const total = products.reduce((res, {price}) => res + (parseInt(price) || 0), 0)

console.log(total)
```